# Why cannot I use 5858 port, even if I don't have duplicated ports or change the port number?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

a typical problem about Node.js when starting. The error is:

```
> demo@1.0.0 dev d:\Proj\WxApp\dev\demo
> egg-bin dev "--debug"
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
2017-09-07 15:31:37,739 INFO 7800 [master] egg version 1.7.0
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

At first I thought it's the problem of duplicated calling ports. So I used something like "netstat -aon|findstr '5858'" before starting VS Code to do debugging. However I didn't see anything left there. The problem just happens when I start VS Code to do debugging——even if I change the "5858", the problem still appears!

Here's my launch.config:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Egg",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "dev",
                "--",
                "--debug"
            ],
            "protocol": "legacy",
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach Agent",
            "port": 5856
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach Worker",
            "restart": true,
            "port": 10086
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Start Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\index.js"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [{
        "name": "Debug",
        "configurations": ["Launch Egg", "Attach Agent", "Attach Worker"]
    }]
}
```

---

This is the image when VSC starts to debug....:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a know node.js issue. This should help.

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/199

Comment: My node is of 6.11. And I'm running on Windows 7 (Professional SP1). And your page doesn't exist at the end:(